# Problems at starting the SonarQube 7.1 web server

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I need help with starting the SonarQube 7.1 web server. I have a Windows 10 64 bit OS and I am running the StartSonar.bat for 64 bit and referencing jdk1.8.0_172. The SonarQube web server is not starting up. Could you please let me know what I am doing wrong? Appreciate it.

Below are the logs.

```
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\temp
2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -server -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headl`enter code here`ess=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\elasticsearch -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch -Epath.conf=C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\temp\conf\es
2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.05.18 15:39:49 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.05.18 15:39:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2018.05.18 15:39:57 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\lib\jdbc\mssql\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\Users\-\Documents\sonarqube-7.1\sonarqube-7.1\temp\sq-process3425829815356357057properties
2018.05.18 15:39:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2018.05.18 15:39:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.05.18 15:39:58 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: please add the log output of the web.log also -> it seems like there is the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I ran the bat file by double clicking on it, it worked.. Now the web server is up.Not sure why it didn't work when I ran the bat from command window.